# how can i focus and move scrollbar in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll, focus

I have a **ListView** and I do some select on the selected change event

```
    private void seleccionarIndexEnLista(int i)
    {
        lstvClientes.Items[i].Selected = true;
        lstvClientes.Items[i].Focused = true;

    }
```

but if the selected item is out of the view and gets selected, the scrollbar doesn't move, so I don't see that it is selected until I move the scrollbar.

Can I move the scrollbar when I do the select in the code to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: C# winforms.
@john i take note for next questions :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lstvClientes.Items[i].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: Somehow, I failed to notice this 100% correct answer before repeating it with my own. If a mod wants to delete mine, feel free. I have marked for deletion as redundant. Oops.

Comment: Yeeeah. But it's a method not a property:
    lstvClientes.Items[lstvClientes.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();

thank you very much